# Clique - Proof OF Authority consensus for private blockchain

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

Just started setting up POA Clique. Having hard time understanding some of the concept. Based on my understanding sealers is the validator of transaction (the one who create blocks) that can be set in genesis file. (My reference https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225)

1. Does the Signers is the sealers, validator and creator only of the block?
2. "**Any signer may only mint 1 block out of every K**". Question - If we have 3 nodes total (all signers), one signer can only sealed/validate/create a block alone ?. e.g. Signer A sealed block 1, Signer B sealed block 2? Two signers can't sealed one block?
3. To ensure there is ever only one majority chain (50% + 1), a signer is only allowed to seal a new block if they had not signed one for the last (len(signers)+1) / 2 blocks. So if there are 3 signers, each signer can only sign every 2nd block (FROM - https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16406).  Does the below is the correct representation assuming I have signers A, B, C?

   Block 1 - Sealed by A

   Block 2 - Sealed by B - can't be seal By A since it already sealed the previous

   Block 3 - Sealed by C - can be seal by A (A have offset to avoid racing blocks) as well. B can't sealed because he sealed the previous

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer  to the best of my knowledge based on my understanding of your questions.

1) The signers are indeed the sealers. In PoA only the authority nodes are able to create (sign and seal) blocks. They put all the pending transactions together, verify them, create a new block and broadcast it.

2) (I understood it as if two signers can seal the same block, and if that was the question:) The answer is no. The signer nodes will take turns to seal blocks.

3) If there are three signers, then they will follow the turns on A-B-C-A-B-C. And interestingly, if you have just two signers (I have tested before) it is just A-B-A-B, so the same signer will indeed mint a block coming after that. Again, this is true for small networks, for larger ones they will ideally never know when they will mint again.

General note: generally PoA will work well for permissioned networks, so issues like 2 and 3 are ideally not going to be big issues.